Volume under a cone and above a disk
To find the volume under the cone
$$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
and above the disk
$$x^2+y^2\leq16$$
I used cylindrical coordinates as follows:
$$x=r\cos(\theta),\qquad y=r\sin(\theta),\qquad z=z$$
with $0\leq r\leq4$ and $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$. Since
$$0\leq z\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
and
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
then
$$0\leq z\leq r$$
Therefore, the volume is given by
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{r}r dzdrd\theta=\frac{128\pi}{3}$$
Is it correct?

Yes , this looks right. A "shortcut" is to notice that this can be easily represented by the double integral $\int^{2\pi}{0} \int^{4}{0}r^2drd\theta $ as it is the volume under a 3D surface (above the xy plane).
